# how to pass yesterday's date argument to cron job

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash script that uses the first argument passed through command line

```
./converse_daily_logs.sh 2019-04-28
```

And I want to set up a cron job. The first argument is CURRENT_DATE - 1, yesterday's date in the format YYYY-MM-DD. How do I accomplish that in a cron job ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`./converse_daily_logs.sh -e $(date +%Y-%m-%d --date '-1 day')`

Comment: Shouldn't those dots be dashes like the OP?